# what's differences between windows and linux about FileInputStream read?

Tags: java, linux, windows, file, fileinputstream

for example, a file size is 1024 bytes that size is the same in windows and linux.
but as I read the file like below

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

for example, in windows, bytes length is 1026 but in linux, bytes length is 1024
or on the contrary to this in windows, bytes length is 1024 but in linux, bytes length is 1022 always in windows bytes length is greater than in linux.

what's differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645/differences-between-unix-and-windows-files?rq=1

Comment: I expect the difference is more to do with Filesystems than Operating systems..

Comment: "wondows"? That's an oddly consistent typo.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are reading a text file and that file has been converted to use windows new lines which are `\r\n` instead of the linux `\n`

If you write text or binary without converting, the files will contain exactly the same bytes and exactly the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are detecting probably has more to do with the Windows vs Unix **line endings**.

As you must be reading the file in text mode, in Windows the end of a line is determined by the two symbols `\r\n` (represented in hexadecimal as `0x0A` and `0x0D` respectively), while in Unix systems it uses only `\n`.

I'll make a wild guess and say your file has two lines. In Windows it will be replacing `\n` by `\r\n` in each line end, creating 2 bytes that don't really exist in the original file.

And in Linux, when reading a file generated in Windows, its doing the opposite, eating 2 bytes.

Comment: but when I parse a file in linux that made by windows filesystem, how to parse the file then get axact original file? not losing \r\n..

Comment: You have to read it in binary mode. But I'm no Java programmer so I'm not sure how to do that in Java.

Comment: FileInputStream is in binary mode, the problem is that the file has been converted when you transferred it between Windows and Linux.

Comment: It is not converted when transfering.