# Text moves to right when outputs to console PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter

I'm coding a really simple server app, so when a client connects to it, it outputs an incrementing number from for-loop each second:

```
int port = 9428;
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println("Waiting for client..");
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Client accepted!");
PrintWriter clientWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clientWriter.write(i + "\n");
    clientWriter.flush();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

clientWriter.close();
client.close();
```

Although the program works fine, it aligns the output in the console in a weird way:

[image]

To connect to server, I use telnet in Windows console: `telnet localhost 9428`

I can't manage why it works in this way, I should be all aligned in one column, as it was done by `System.out.println(i)`.

Anyone has the same issue and knows how to fix it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645/differences-between-unix-and-windows-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on Windows so you must use Windows line end `\r\n`. You can get it from [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) instead of hardcoding.

```
clientWriter.write(i + System.lineSeparator());
```

or use [`PrintWriter.println(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(int)) which will output the line separator after the value:

```
clientWriter.println(i);
```

Comment: As I understood, using `System.lineSeparator()` is more preferable, because it works as it has to on both Windows and Unix? Edit: just read the edited answer, thanks.

Comment: @nklymok yes, it's best to use Java idioms instead of hardcoding.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows the newline consists of CR (carriage return) + LF (line feed) characters.

In a client-server setting you should use `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` depending on the client platform (Windows or *nix).

Other solutions such as `println()` and `System.lineSeparator()` will work differently depending on the platform the *server* is running on (not the client).